# How can I slightly modify an emacs powerline theme?

Tags: themes, powerline

The screenshot below is my current emacs powerline:

[image: emacs-powerline]

I'm pretty happy with the theme, but I'd like to slightly change the color of the text in the blue areas.

What can I put in my `.emacs` file to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest that you use the `customize` facility to effect the change you want.  If you insist on setting the color in the `.emacs`, you can copy the code from `custom.el` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to start is with

```
M-x list-faces-display
```

This will open a buffer which shows the names for all currently defined faces and show their current setting. If you click on one of the face names, it will open up a customiz-face buffer where you can change the face settings. Save the changes and they will be written to the custom section of your init file.

Note that powerline uses a combination of powerline specific faces and mode-line specific faces. I cannot tell exactly which faces are involved from your screen shot, but you should be able to identify them with the list-faces-display command.

Comment: This works, and is a more satisfactory solution than sds's. (Still, I don't understand why this question was migrated when it had already been answered?)